# Hidden markov model - features

Tags: hidden-markov-models

i am using Baum-Welch-algorithm to learn the parameters of a hidden markov model to use it to determine an optmial labeling sequence of a named entity recognition task (via viterbi algorithm).

I'v tried a simple example with random a-priori-distribution and random transion and emission probabilities.

Now, i am thinking how i can involve features, e.g. a feature which fires if the word ends with the suffix "ing".

Which role does features have in context of HMM?